# How to permanently change navigator.useragent in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent, developer-tools

I use Google Chrome version 55.0.2883.87 m.

When developer tool is on, the value of navigator.userAgent comes as : Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Mobile Safari/537.36

When developer tool is off, the value comes as : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)

I found a hack to change the userAgent for the current tab via http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/

But I want this change to stay there even if I open a different tab.
So , is there any way I can do it ?

Answer (score 6):

/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --user-agent="_USER_AGENT_STRING_" %U

Comment: Also works with chromium, even if --help doesn't show documentation for --user-agent.